# Return 204 Status Code on IQueryable<Log> Web API Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rest

I am exporting a large amount of data using `web api` to `JSON` and a `custom CVS` parser. Everything works fine but I want to return the `204 status code` when the query returns 0 records. I do not find a way to set the status code in action because I return `IQueryable<Log>` in action. Any suggestion?

```
   [HttpGet]
   [Route("user/statistic")]

    public IQueryable<Log> Statistic(int userId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        var logs = _context.Find(userId, startDate, endDate);
        return logs;
    }

    public IQueryable<Log> Find(int userId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        var startDateSql = startDate.AddDays(-1).Date;
        var endDateTimeSql = endDate.AddDays(1).Date;
        return Logs.Where(w => w.UserId == userId && w.DateStamp > startDateSql && w.DateStamp < endDateTimeSql).AsNoTracking();
    }
```

Comment: HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 204; Worth trying

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `IActionResult` instead of `IQueryable` for your API methods
then you can have something like this:

```
public IActionResult MyApi()
{
    // if the result has any item
    return Ok(result);

    // otherwise
    return NoContent(); // which returns 204 status code
}
```

Comment: I can't execute IQueryable<Log> in Action, I am passing it down to Formatter and let them handle a large amount of data. You suggest executing the whole query in action and that big performance penalty in my situation.

Comment: when you are receiving the response it does not matter the query is executed and no different with IActionResult, if it was in the method it was a performance optimization, but generally, it is not recommended to use IEnumerable, Iquerable etc for the result of HTTP endpoints then you can produce reasonable responses

Comment: Ok, please take my code and merge it along with your code, and do not forget to insert a cancelation token to let the web action cancel querying data from the database when the connection is dropped. As you quickly find out that all data is fetched at once in Action and there is no way to create chunk reads from database using your suggestions. That's why I use  IQueryable<Log>, I do not find another way around when large amount fo data should be returned.